# Failure trying to import old wallet.dat

Tags: wallet.dat

I found an old wallet.dat, but I cannot import it and I don't know why.

Comment: And why exactly can't you import it?

Comment: @D.H. Is it safe to link to a wallet.dat file publicly? I assume it's encrypted, but I wasn't sure if I should remove the link or not when I edited the question.

Comment: @JohnBensin I assumed it was encrypted too and it that case there's no real danger. It's probably unnecessary in order for people to help though, so removing the link is fine with me... we shouldn't really encourage people to post their wallet files.

Comment: @D.H. That was my thought too; I went ahead and removed the link.

Answer (score 2):

First off, is this your wallet. I know this is a dumb question but I always have to ask. Also, was this wallet "encrypted"? What version of the wallet did you use and was this wallet based on the same application you are using now.

For example, Bitcoin Wallet Qt, you have to match it with the same product. I've noticed for example if I tried my wallet import doesn't work on other Bitcoin wallet applications, even if I have the password for the encryption correct.

This should really be answered by the developer of said wallet and since I don't know which wallet you're using, I can't help you at the current time in this regard.